# Error initializing pointer to vector using unordered_map value

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, constants, object-composition

I have a class called street_map that contains a map with int keys and values of type `vector<edge>`. In one of the methods, I am trying to initialize a pointer to the `vector<edge>` value to get its contents.

```
class street_map {
public:
    explicit street_map (const std::string &filename);
    bool geocode(const std::string &address, int &u, int &v, float &pos) const;
    bool route3(int source, int target, float &distance) const {
        auto it = adjacencyList.find(source);
        vector<edge>* v = &(it->second);
        return true;
    }
private:
    unordered_map<side , vector<segment>> map;
    unordered_map<int, vector<edge>> adjacencyList;
};
```

The line `vector<edge>* v = &(it->second);` gives the error:

`Cannot initialize a variable of type 'vector<edge> *' with an rvalue of type 'const std::__1::vector<edge, std::__1::allocator<edge> > *'`

Here is the edge class:

```
class edge {
    int node;
    string street;
    float length;
    int startingNode;
public:
    edge(int startingNode, int node, string street, float length) {
        startingNode = startingNode;
        node = node;
        street = street;
        length = length;
    }
};
```

I am wondering if this is because of the const keyword and how to fix this if it because of the const keyword (I am supposed to keep the const keyword, but I suppose I can get rid of it if there is no other solution).

Comment: Most probably `it` is a const_iterator. So you either need a non-const iterator or you must assign your vector to a const pointer.

Comment: `route3` is a const member function => `adjacencyList` is const within it => `find` returns a const_iterator.

Comment: Is `const vector<edge>* v = &(it->second);` acceptable in your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four options:

### 1) Make the pointer to the vector const

You will not be able to modify the vector.

```
bool route3(int source, int target, float &distance) const {
        auto it = adjacencyList.find(source);
        const vector<edge>* v = &(it->second);
        return true;
    }
```

### 2) Make your adjacencyList mutable

mutable means accessible as non-const from a const function - this can be risky if you don't pay attention to your access design!

```
private:
    unordered_map<side , vector<segment>> map;
    mutable unordered_map<int, vector<edge>> adjacencyList;
```

### 3) Copy the vector

This might introduce a heavier overhead and changes done to the vector are NOT stored in your map.

```
vector<edge> v = (it->second);
```

### 4) Make the function non-const

Be aware that this way the function cannot be called in a context where `street_map` is const!

```
bool route3(int source, int target, float &distance) {
        auto it = adjacencyList.find(source);
        vector<edge>* v = &(it->second);
        return true;
    }
```